# Why do numpy array turns int into float

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-dtype

I'm trying to fill an array with integers, but it seems like numpy array keep turning the integers into floats. Why is this happening and how do I stop this?

```
arr = np.empty(9)
arr[3] = 7
print(arr[3])
>>>7.0
```

Comment: Have you checked the data type of `arr` before assigning `arr[3]`?

Comment: The default dtype for np.empty is float: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html

Comment: @AnkitJaiswal That is _not_, and never was, an appropriate reason for closure. At best, it's a reason to downvote, which you could have done instead.

Comment: thanks, @user2285236, I will have to specify the data type when using np.empty()

Answer (score 10, accepted):

NumPy arrays, unlike Python lists, can contain only a single type, which (as far as I know) is set at creation time. Everything you put into the array gets converted to that type.

By default, the data type is assumed to be `float`. To set another type, you can pass `dtype` to the `empty` function like this:

```
>>> arr = np.empty(9, dtype=int)
>>> arr[3] = 7
>>> arr[3]
7
```