# Assinging submatrix to matrix in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I wrote a some code to compute [householder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation) reduction to [Hessenberg form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessenberg_matrix)

```
V = []
m,n = A.shape
for i in range(m-1):
    x = A[i+1:,i]
    e1 = np.zeros(x.shape)
    e1[0] = 1
    v = sgn(x[0])*np.linalg.norm(x)*e1 + x  
    v = v/np.linalg.norm(v)
    V.append(v) 
    vv = np.outer(v,v)
    print(A[i+1:,i:]-2*vv @ A[i+1:,i:])
    A[i+1:,i:] =A[i+1:,i:]-2*vv @ A[i+1:,i:]
    print(A)
    A[:,i+1:] = A[:,i+1:] - 2 *  np.outer(A[:,i+1:] @ v,v)
```

I run this code with A =

```
[[1,2,3],
 [2,4,5],
 [1,3,2]]
```

The first print statement prints

```
[[-2.23606798 -4.91934955 -5.36656315]
 [ 0.          0.89442719 -0.4472136 ]]
```

Which is what makes sense.
While the second prints

```
[[ 1  2  3]
 [-2 -4 -5]
 [ 0  0  0]]
```

And this don't make sense.

Why do they print differently?
If this kind of assignment don't work, is there some other smart way?

Comment: What is `sgn` - we cannot run your code - please read [mre].  Maybe you can reduce your example to just some simple assignments - which looking at your code, should work.

Comment: I've getting `RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide v = v/np.linalg.norm(v)` with this `A` matrix, I've change `A` to `np.array([[1,2,3], [2.5,4,5],  [1,3,2]])` and result looking normal.

Comment: Looks like your question is: `How do I assign floats to an array of ints` or something like that.  I imagine there is an answer on SO or in the documentation.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/51607679/2823755](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51607679/2823755) ,

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign floats to an array of ints.  Here is a quick fix - Change the dtype before operating on it.

```
A = np.array([[1,2,3],
              [2,4,5],
              [1,3,2]])

b = np.array([[-2.23606798, -4.91934955, -5.36656315],
              [ 0.,          0.89442719, -0.4472136 ]])

A = A.astype('float64')
A[1:,0:] = b

print(A)
```

---

```
>>>
[[ 1.          2.          3.        ]
 [-2.23606798 -4.91934955 -5.36656315]
 [ 0.          0.89442719 -0.4472136 ]]
>>>
```

---

From [the documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/1.19/user/basics.indexing.html?#assigning-values-to-indexed-arrays) regarding indexing/assignments:

> Note that assignments may result in changes if assigning higher types to lower types (like floats to ints) or even exceptions (assigning complex to floats or ints):