# Why is numpy telling me that I can't convert a float NaN when I'm actually trying to convert an int?

Tags: python, numpy

Here is a simple numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([15, 22, 3])
```

I want to transform the second value into nan:

```
x[1] = np.nan
```

It returns the following error:

```
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

print(type(x[1]))  # this returns "<class 'numpy.int32'>"
```

I managed to replace the required value with NaN by transforming the array of ints into an array of floats.

**But still**.
Why is numpy telling me that I can't convert a *float NaN* when I'm actually trying to convert an *int*?

Thank you

Comment: `np.nan` is a float value. There is no `int` `nan`, therefore numpy can't convert `np.nan` into an `int`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `numpy`, `nan` is a special `float`:

```
>>> type(np.nan)
<class 'float'>
```

I call it a special type of float because normally Python won't complain if you try to add both `int` and `float` into a single numpy array since the integers will automatically be converted to `float`:

```
>>> x = np.array([-1, float(10.12)])
>>> x
>> array([-1.  , 10.12])
```

but this is not the case for [`numpy.nan`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/constants.html?highlight=nan#numpy.nan):

> IEEE 754 floating point representation of Not a Number (NaN).

---

I would suggest to either create a numpy array of floats:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([15.0, 22.0, 3.0])
x[1] = np.nan

>>> array([15., nan,  3.])
```

or try to represent `nan` using an alternative integer value if your use-case allows this representation. For instance use `-1` to represent `nan` (for example this would make sense if in your use case you don't have negative values).

---

Alternatively, you can use a `list` that allows you to store objects of different data type:

```
l = [15, 22, 3]
l[1] = np.nan

>>> [15, nan, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

> By default, the data type is assumed to be float.

As stated in https://stackoverflow.com/a/51607679/11501135, NumPy arrays default the data type of the array to `float`.

Comment: Not sure if this is true anymore. If you try `x = np.array([15, 22, 3]); print(x.dtype)`, it does print `int64` in numpy `1.19.2`

Comment: I think the issue is what @Giorgos Myrianthous explained, np.nan itself is float and you can't insert that into an array of `ints`

Comment: @Ananda - This answer is not correct in multiple ways.