# Decimals dissapear after loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, decimal

I'm currently doing some school exercises, but keep running into troubles in one. I'm rotating and scaling a vector-set around a center point. Its seems like I'm close as my numbers are really close the answers, but they are rounded. I've tried making everything floats (through early and late determint them, but also by loops), but they still disappear.  My code looks like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import math

def rotateScale(coordinates, center, theta, scale):
  
    new=np.copy(coordinates)
    new[1,:]=0
    new[0,:]=0
    
 
    for n in range(len(coordinates[0,:])):
    #for n in range(1):
        for i in range(len(new[:,n])):
            new[i,n]=float(new[i,n])
            
        matrix=np.reshape([math.cos(theta),-1*math.sin(theta),math.sin(theta),math.cos(theta)],[2,2])
        matrix2=coordinates[:,n]-center
        new[:,n]=np.dot(matrix,matrix2)*scale+center
    newCoordinates=new
        
    return newCoordinates

print(rotateScale(np.array([[1,3,3,4,7,6,1],[1,1,2,3,3,5,5]]), np.array([5,2]), -math.pi/3, 2))
```

my output comes out like this

```
[[ 0  1  2  5  8 11  6]
 [ 7  4  5  4  0  3 11]]
```

but it should be like this:

```
[[ -0.73205081   1.26794919   3. 5.73205081   8.73205081  11.19615242   6.19615242]
[  7.92820323   4.46410162   5.46410162   4.73205081  -0.46410162   3.26794919  11.92820323]]
```

Anyone who knows what's happening? :)

Comment: `print(rotateScale(np.array([[1,3,3,4,7,6,1],[1,1,2,3,3,5,5]],dtype=float), np.array([5,2],dtype=float), -math.pi/3, 2))`

Comment: https://scipy-lectures.org/intro/numpy/elaborate_arrays.html#casting

Comment: Related:[Why do numpy array turns int into float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51607607/why-do-numpy-array-turns-int-into-float),

Comment: You are assigning floats to an array of integer type - the dtype of the elements in the array have to be homogenous so the float is converted to an int. You could also change the function with `new=np.copy(coordinates.astype(float))` then you could still pass it int arrays.

Comment: Thanks that helped alot !! Just to be sure i understand what was wrong. The mistake was that the input, "coordinates" was an array with integers? or does the np.copy command change it, for as what I understand by default arrays are of a float type

Comment: `np.array([[1,3,3,4,7,6,1],[1,1,2,3,3,5,5]]).dtype --> dtype('int32')` - your function arguments are/were *integer arrays*. There was nothing actually **wrong** - you just didn't understand why the assignment of a float to an integer array resulted in an integer. Depending on the circumstances that behaviour might be desirable.